# javascript function after successful login

Tags: fbconnect, django-authentication, django-allauth

I'm using `django-allauth`, so when i call `"/accounts/facebook/login"` from my homepage, the FB dialog box opens up, and the redirect URL is the homepage only.

Now, I want to run a `Javascript` function when the user is redirected to the homepage after successful login. The sad part is I have no idea how to do do this. The function is to open a popup, but thats a different thing.

Answer (score 0):

if user is loged in, you can send that condition to your template with context like so..

```
context = {
'hede': 'hodo', etc..... 
'user_loged_in': True
}
```

than, at your template

```
{% if user_loged_in %}
<script>alert('stuff');</script>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't this run that js function everytime the user goes to the homepage. The function opens up a popup, and when a logged in user is on some other page and comes to the homepage, I dont want to show the popup each time, just want to show it when the user is redirected after successful FB login.